# WPF how to apply binding to the view with current method

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to convert my window/form to use viewmodel binding. However, When I use this method, I get this error:

> BindingExpression path error: 'DocumentTypeFieldDetailsViewModel'
>   property not found on 'object' ''DocumentTypeFieldDetailsViewModel'
>   (HashCode=13055244)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=DocumentTypeFieldDetailsViewModel.Order;
>   DataItem='DocumentTypeFieldDetailsViewModel' (HashCode=13055244);
>   target element is 'TextBox' (Name='OrderTextBox'); target property is
>   'Text' (type 'String')

This is the datacontext i've declare over this view

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:DocumentTypeFieldDetailsViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

EDIT: I removed the datacontext from the xaml

This is one of my textboxes in my view:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Order"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="OrderTextBox" PreviewTextInput="NumberValidation_PreviewTextInput"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding DocumentTypeFieldDetailsViewModel.Order}/>
</Grid>
```

This is my viewmodel

```
public class DocumentTypeFieldDetailsViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public string DocumentTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I load the data when the window is loaded

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.DataContext = new DocumentTypeFieldDetailsViewModel();
    if (IsNew != true)
    {
        var dtd = fieldData.Get(FieldId);
        if (dtd == null)
        {
            Error("Field not found");
            this.Close();
        }
        DocumentTypeFieldDetailsViewModel dtfevm = new DocumentTypeFieldDetailsViewModel
        {
            Id = dtd.Id,
            Name = dtd.Name,
            Description = dtd.Description,
            DocumentTypeId = dtd.DocumentTypeId,
            Order = dtd.Order,
            OrganizationId = dtd.OrganizationId
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: You are assigning datacontext both in xaml and code behind. It is not correct. Set datacontext either way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the datacontext is bound to instance of DocumentTypeFieldDetailsViewModel, u should access its properties directly.

Error indicates that, datacontext has no property of DocumentTypeFieldDetailsViewModel.Order, because u are binding to the instance of the DocumentTypeFieldDetailsViewModel.

```
 <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="OrderTextBox" 
  PreviewTextInput="NumberValidation_PreviewTextInput"
  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Order}/> //here u can access the property Order directly.
```

For more info check out the [how-to-create-a-simple-binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-create-a-simple-binding)

Assign values in Xaml as follow. Otherwise u can use the object that u created from datasource and assign the datacontext in code behind and remove datacontext in xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:DocumentTypeFieldDetailsViewModel
        Order="SomeOrder"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Sorry I tried your method and nothing appears. I set the remove the this.DataContext line and set it in the xaml side instead and nothing appeared.

Comment: U need to set values of the object also in xaml, check the edit. I believe you must have just created object. Can you posted updated code. Has the error disappeared?

Comment: Assign the datacontext in code behind and remove from xaml

Comment: Thats what I did. I assigned the datacontext in the code behind, removed from xaml but still nothing appears.

Comment: Are there any errors? feel free to update the code u tried. Without which it would be difficult to discuss what went wrong

Comment: I updated my question. From my existing code, i removed the xaml data context and declared the viewmodel in my window_loaded

Comment: I realized what the issue was. my this.datacontext was empty. I had to assign my viewmodel to it afterwards.

Comment: Assign "dtfevm" as datacontent.

Comment: Haha noticed it at the same time. Thank you!